# Configure Spring batch admin to use db2 database

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

In order to configure spring batch admin UI to use db2 database, I referred the Admin UI documentation which says **"launch the application with a system property -DENVIRONMENT=[type]."**  I understand that **"-DENVIRONMENT=db2**" should be kept in some file. I tried by keeping in **batch-default.properties** file, but that did not work. Since I am using WLP(liberty server), tried by keeping in server.xml file, no help. Still in the console I see env-context.xml file from batch admin is still loading batch-hsql.properties file(default configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My job is written using Spring Boot so I put property, `ENVIRONMENT=db2` in `application.properties` and add a new file - `batch-db2.properties` at same location as application.properties.

Few compulsory properties will be needed there like - you need to try an experiment,

```
batch.job.configuration.package=
batch.drop.script=classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-db2.sql
batch.schema.script=
batch.business.schema.script=

#Copied from batch.properties of spring-batch-admin-manager API project
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.data.source.init=false
batch.job.configuration.file.dir=target/config
batch.job.service.reaper.interval=60000
batch.files.upload-dir=/sba/input
```

I had put DB connection information too but later I moved to JNDI by overriding file - `data-source-context.xml` in `META-INF\spring\batch\override` like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionPool" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

`ConnectionPool` is db connection pool JNDI name from server.

Keeping configurations in your code lets you freely move your app to different servers without asking for server specific configurations first.

Answer (score 0):

Not really familiar with liberty server, but the link below says that system properties need to be added to jvm.options file. See link below :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html

Comment: Created jvm.options file under usr/shared folder and placed "-DENVIRONMENT=db2. With this spring batch admin UI started invoking batch-db2.properties file. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. There is another way to override it if jvm  environment variable was not an option for you. Anyways, please accept the answer and upvote so that anyone else coming to this thread could apply the same solution.